# Normal map seams SFM import to Blender

Tags: uv, normal-map

Just to preface I'm new to blender and all 3d software. I have an object I imported into blender from SFM. I notice on some objects that there are seams when the normal map is used. Even if I just load a blank image, there are noticeable seam issues when a normal map node is connected.

I'll share several images to show what the issue is. I've tried converting to quads, removing doubles, recalculating normals and nothing seems to work. I've tried texture painting them but it doesn't work for these seams. I've manually selected faces and flipped normals and it still has a seam.

All normals are facing the right way. The normal map itself doesn't have seams (if I view it in texture painting). I imagine it's an issue with the UV mapping but I'm not sure I can fix it without a deeper understanding of UV mapping.

The first image is the normal map and texture applied showing the seam:

[image]

The second image I removed the normal map texture but there's still a seam and shadow issue:

[image]

In this image I disconnected the normal map node and it has no seam.

[image]

Here's the mesh polygons, no messed up edges or anything:

[image]

No normal map or texture, mesh looks fine:

[image]

In the final image I have no texture and no normal map texture, but the blank normal map causes these messed up seams.

[image]

For this particular model it's not really a big deal, but I have some human models that the same thing happens on. Is this just an issue of the original source or is there any options I can change to fix the issue?

Comment: The last pic with the empty image texture connected to the normal node is always going to look wrong, the colour used for a missing image is not the same as the 'neutral' normal map colour so it will always distort normals.